# How to calculate the difference of two dates

Tags: php, date

I have two dates assigned in variable $date1 and $date2..
Here is the code..

```
if (isset($_POST['check_in']))
{
 $date1=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['check_in']));
}
if (isset($_POST['check_in']))
{
 $date2=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['check_out']));
}
```

For example if `date1="2015-05-21"` and `date2="2015-05-23"`.I want the difference of date as 2

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime` class. Try with -

```
$date1=new DateTime("2015-05-21");
$date2=new DateTime("2015-05-23");

$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

**Output**

```
+2 days
```

[DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Code with various examples.

Here's one I like:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2015-05-21');
$datetime2 = date_create('2015-05-23');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `strtotime` returns unixtime, the difference in seconds can be calculated by simply subtracting the one `strtotime` from the other:

```
$seconds = strtotime($_POST['check_out']) - strtotime($_POST['check_in']);
```

Then to find the days:

```
$days = $seconds / 60 / 60 / 24;
```